# Wrong number of arguments error(1 for 0) in Posts controller, rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.1

I am getting the error message "wrong number of arguments error(1 for 0) in my posts controller in my show action.  I will comment the end of that specific line.  Thanks for the help.

```
def show
  @post = Post.all(:order => 'created_at DESC') #this is the error line
end

def new
  @post = Post.new
end

def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])

  if @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  else
   render :new
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either have to show 1 post, and it will be:

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id]) # show
```

or all posts

```
@posts = Post.order('created_at DESC') # index
```

Taking into account the fact, you write this in `show` action, you probably meant first.

---

Also small recommendation regarding [strong parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters).
Instead of writing this `@post = Post.new(params[:post])` you would rather want to write in `#create`:

```
@post = Post.new(post_params) 

private

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body) #whatsoever your post has
end
```

Comment: Okay I made the changes in order to show 1 post.  Now it just routes to the create view when a new post is created.  What should my show view look like?

Comment: What routes you to create?

Comment: I just used resource routes.  => resources :posts

Comment: Create show.html.erb and paste `<h1>Posts</h1>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  Title: <%= post.title %><br>
<% end %>` and so you can add any post's fields..

Comment: Okay thanks, I still can't figure out why it is going to the create view instead of the show view after a new post is made..

Answer (score 6):

You'll want to read the the latest [Rails Active Record Query Interface Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html). A lot has changed lately. The short answer is that you now chain together conditions. And `.all` does not take any arguments -- as the error message is telling you. Instead, you want to use the `.order()` method:

```
@posts = Post.order(created_at: :desc)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why there's a downvote on this. It is correct that `.all` no longer takes any arguments in version 4.1. In the previous 4.0 version, I believe you could still use the old option parameters in `.all`, but no longer.